# NLTK (or other) Part of speech tagger that returns n-best tag sequences

Tags: nltk, pos-tagger

I need a part of speech tagger that does not just return the optimal tag sequence for a given sentence, but that returns the n-best tag sequences.  So for 'time flies like an arrow', it could return both NN VBZ IN DT NN and NN NNS VBP DT NN for example, ordered in terms of their probability.  I need to train the tagger using my own tag set and sentence examples, and I would like a tagger that allows different features of the sentence to be engineered.  If one of the nltk taggers had this functionality, that would be great, but any tagger that I can interface with my Python code would do.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a look at [spaCy](https://spacy.io/). From what I have seen, it doesn't by default allow you to return the top-n tags, but it supports [creating custom pipeline components](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#section-custom-components).

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2087) on Github where exactly this is discussed, and there are some suggestions on how to implement it relatively quickly.